# Creating a frequency distribution table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, frequency-distribution, frequency-table

I'm new to Python and Pandas, and i'm struggling to create a frequency distribution table form my df.

My dataframe is something like this:

| Balances | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 7 |
| 11 | 15 |
| 12 | 30 |
| 13 | 20 |
| 10 | 15 |
| 13 | 20 |

edit: The balance numbers are its respective ID

I need the frequency of each balance used (in this example, balance 10 would be 2 and so on) the min, max and mean of the measurements results.

I was to use df.groupby(['balances']) but how can i use the results form using df.groupby to creat a new table? Is that the way?

Comment: `df.groupby('Balances').describe()` (or `df.groupby('Balances')['Weight'].describe()`) will give you a lot of information for every column within the group

Comment: With this i can create a new df based on the values given by .describe, right?

Comment: Yes, if you assign it to something: `df1 = df.groupby('Balances').describe()`, then you have a DataFrame (with a column Multiindex) that you can select from or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `groupby`, instead use [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
In [1619]: df.Balances.value_counts()
Out[1619]: 
10    2
13    2
11    1
12    1
Name: Balances, dtype: int64
```

To create another `df`, do this:

```
In [1628]: df1 = df.Balances.value_counts().reset_index(name='Frequency').rename(columns={'index':'Balances'})

In [1629]: df1
Out[1629]: 
   Balances  Frequency
0        10          2
1        13          2
2        11          1
3        12          1
```

Comment: and to add the min, max and mean i would follow the same logic?

Comment: For that you'll have to use groupby.

Comment: actually that is not what i needed, it helped a bit tho. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

`df.groupby(['balances']).count()` should solve what you're looking for